# Python asyncio retry for 200 response with specific result

Tags: python, async-await, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm in a situation where I need to retry async request even when the request returns 200 response. For some specific cases, I need to check if there's a key in the output. If so, we need to retry. The following sample code (which can be executed in a Jupyter notebook) works for retries whenever the request fails (non-200). How can I tweak this to cater to this particular need?

P.S. Ideally, the response should've been non-200 but this is the option I'm left with.

```
# load required libraries
import json
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from async_retrying import retry

base_url = "http://localhost:1050/hello?rid="

# async ginger call
@retry(attempts=3)
async def async_ginger_call():
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=3)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        async with session.post(url, raise_for_status=True, timeout=300) as response:

            result = await response.text()

            # condition here; if key in result then retry

            return json.loads(result)

reqs = 2
tasks = []
connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=reqs)
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
    for i in range(reqs):
        url = base_url + str(i)

        # encode sentence
        tasks.append(async_ginger_call())

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
```

Sample flask server code

```
# sample api
import time
import json
import datetime
from flask import Flask, request
from flask import Response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def welcome():
    rid = request.args.get('rid', default=3, type=int)

    valid_response = json.dumps({
    "Result": {
        "Warnings": [
                {
                    "Code": 1100,
                    "Message": "A technical error occurred during execution."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    )

    # testing for failure
    if rid == 2:
        # pass
        # return valid_response
        return Response("{'Result': ''}", status=500, mimetype='application/json')

    return valid_response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1050)
```

Comment: `for i in range(reqs):` never sends 2

Comment: @MauriceMeyer we can update the `reqs` param, that's not the problem. Qn is how to retry when there're `Warnings` for example in the response.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly, but can't you just check your condition and raise `ClientResponseError` if you need a retry?

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword that works! Is it a recommended practice?